# Latex - putting an image in the right place(Overleaf)

Tags: graphics, floats, wide-image

i'm working on an online Latex editor called Overleaf ,i was trying to put an image in the right place just after a specific paragraph , but it appears in the next page ..

```
\textbf{Selon Google trends}, Odoo est l'ERP Open source le plus recherch\'e dans le monde pendant les derniers 12 mois.\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=15cm]{images/class.png} 
\captionof{figure}{Les ERP les plus recherch\'es pendant les 12 derniers mois} 
\label{class_google}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image: The result]

PS: i imported `\usepackage{float}` ,`\usepackage{graphicx}` , `\usepackage{caption}`

**PLEASE HELP , i have a graduation Project =(**

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What you observe is the floating behavior of the figure environment. If you do not want you image to float, don't use the figure environment. Also, why do you use captionof inside of a figure environment?

Comment: Some quick remarks: The picture seems to be too big to fit on the page, so it is moved to the next. If you don't want it float, don't use a floating environment, i.e. `figure`

Comment: But i need to use it otherwise i can't have the  list of figures at the end  , it's for my graduation project report =(

Comment: Unrelated why are you using captionof inside a normal figure? Caption would be enough. Additionally you should not be using center to center an image inside a float it introduces extra vertical spacing (making the necessary area for the float too large)

Comment: That's why you are using `\captionof` instead of `\caption`

Comment: If you use captionof and drop the figure environment, the list of figures will still contain this image.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks it worked + i reduced the width a little bit , You saved my life xD